# HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Tags: apache2

What does this mean, and why does it appear on bottom of ALL html, php, css, js files?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2009 00:35:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

I am running a nph-proxy.cgi script.

I already turned off ServerSignatures, and set it to Production in apache2.conf.

**UPDATE:**

I am rewriting

```
myproxysite.com/http/someothersite.com
```

to

```
 myproxysite.com/cgi-bin/nph-proxy.cgi/http/someothersite.com
```

and this HTTP header is shown at bottom of each page.

However, when i remove the Rewrite Rules, this problem is gone !! Meaning when i access the proxy via myproxiste.com/cgi-bin/nph-proxy.cgi/http/someothersite.com, the HTTP header is NOT found at the bottom.

Comment: Soo... did you solve the problem?  You should post the answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Hi time, i updated the question. i discovered a condition that causes this to happen. i have added it above.

Answer (score 5):

Those look like the server headers and should not be presented by the browser.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 ok
```

Means that the server is responding using the HTTP protocol version 1.1. 200 is the code used when everything is ok.

```
Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2009 00:35:42
```

The date of the server...

```
GMTServer: Apache
```

The name of the server

```
Content-Length: 0
```

The size of the content ( in this case 0 bytes )

```
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
```

How long the connection will remain open.

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Is the connection to be closed or no

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

What is the [mime type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type) of the contet ( HTML would be `text/html` )

You can see here a list of [HTTP Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers)

After the headers are displayed, you'll have the html content ( the web page )

As for your last question, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

That is a typical set of HTTP Response headers.  It is information sent by the server to describe the content which is being sent, as well as the status (meta-information) of the request for a particular resource.  Check out the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

These headers normally appear *before* the content and the browser "eats" them so that you never see them.  The fact that you're seeing them at the end of documents implies that something, probably `nph-proxy.cgi` is appending them to the output on each request.  This could be a bug, or more likely just a simple misconfiguration.

Comment: its something to do with the Rewrite Rule...when i remove it, this problem is gone.